# Sum of the first elem of a 3-tuples list

Tags: haskell, tuples

I'm new around programming stuff :/

I need to make a function that retrieve the sum of the first element from a 3-tuple list.

I have something like:

```
tuples = [(11,"11","11"),(22,"22","22"),(33,"33","33"),(44,"44","44"),(55,"55","55"),(66,"66","66")]
```

And I need the sum of the first element of each 3-tuple from the list. = 11+22+33+44+55

Pattern matching maybe? map?

Comment: sorry...list. = 11+22+33+44+55+66   :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `sum` with a [list comprehension](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension):

```
sum [x | (x, _, _) <- tuples]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want something [pointfree](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree), you could try:

```
> let f = sum . map (\(x, _, _) -> x)
> f [(11,"11","11"),(22,"22","22"),(33,"33","33")]
66
```

Note: this has point `x`, which we can not avoid because of the `fst3 :: (a,b,c) -> a` built-in lack

Comment: Why did you call `(\(x,_,_) -> x)` as 'point-free'? Actually it has "point" x.

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙ Sorry for my english. My point was this is the most pointfree version that OP can achieve without unsafe coerse, that i should not recommend.