# How to sum a sequence of 3-tuples? And calculate their average?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have a sequence of 3-tuples like this:

```
[(123, 143 ,136), (177, 284, 248), (143, 182, 252)...]
```

and I would like to them into single 3-tuple by summing all the 3-tuples:

```
[((x1+x2+x3),(y1+y2+y3),(z1+z2+z3))]
```

and then find their average

```
[((x1+x2+x3)/n,(y1+y2+y3)/n,(z1+z2+z3)/n)]
```

My attempt of summing them up:

```
let averageRGB seqRGB = seqRGB |> Seq.fold(fun(R, G, B)(r, g, b) -> (R+r, G+g, B+b)) (0, 0, 0) (r, g, b)
```

I tried using:

[How do you sum up and average a Sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824274/how-do-you-sum-up-and-average-a-sequence)

[Sum of the first elem of a 3-tuples list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373631/sum-of-the-first-elem-of-a-3-tuples-list)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/776d6f05-40c9-43ac-9b1c-eab188466eed/f-how-to-use-foldback-for-array-of-tuples?forum=fsharpgeneral

Answer (score 9):

In your sample, the last expression `(r, g, b)` is not needed. Without it, your code correctly sums the values. Using upper-case names for variables is not particularly idiomatic, so I'd write it as:

```
let averageRGB seqRGB = 
  seqRGB |> Seq.fold (fun (r1,g1,b1) (r2,g2,b2) -> (r1+r2, g1+g2, b1+b2)) (0, 0, 0)
```

To calculate the average, you just need to divide the result by the count of elements. You could do that using `Seq.length` to get the length of the sequence, but this would iterate over the sequence again. So, it is perhaps better to keep the count as another parameter in the state of `fold`:

```
let averageRGB seqRGB = 
  let r,g,b,count = seqRGB |> Seq.fold (fun (r1,g1,b1,count) (r2,g2,b2) ->
        (r1+r2, g1+g2, b1+b2, count+1)) (0, 0, 0, 0)
  (r/count, g/count, b/count)
```

Note that this uses integers to do the calculation - so it will also do integer division. If you're working with floats, you can just change the `0` constants to `0.0` and F# will infer that the function works on floats.

If you wanted a fancier solution, then you can define your own type to represent colors. For a right type definition, you can get average using just `Seq.average`. So, if you wanted to use a record type, you could write:

```
type Color =
 { R : int; G : int; B : int }
 static member (+) (c1, c2) =
  { R = c1.R + c2.R; G = c1.G + c2.G; B = c1.B + c2.B }
 static member DivideByInt(c, n) =
  { R = c.R / n; G = c.G / n; B = c.B / n} 
 static member Zero = { R=0; G=0; B=0 }
```

The record has an overloaded `+` operator, `Zero` member and `DivideByInt` method, which makes the following possible:

```
[ {R=255;G=0;B=0}; {R=0;G=128;B=255} ]
|> Seq.average
```

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact that you have to divide by number of elements to get average (that part is already missing in OP code).

Comment: Hah I see, upper/lowercase doesn't work. When I test this line of code, it said error FS0001: The type 'int * int * int' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'

Comment: I really like your solution of adding static members to a record to enable the type to work with Seq.average, and would only add that one way to discover such things when one doesn't have a Tomas Petricek around to help out is to examine the type signature: `Seq.average : seq<^T> -> ^T (requires ^T with static member (+) and ^T with static member DivideByInt and ^T with static member Zero)`

Answer (score 1):

Let's take it one step at a time (listings from F# Interactive, to show how type inference deals with our code).

1. Sum two 3-tuples:

   ```
   > let sumRGB (r1,g1,b1) (r2,g2,b2) = (r1+r2, g1+g2, b1+b2);;

   val sumRGB :
     r1:int * g1:int * b1:int -> r2:int * g2:int * b2:int -> int * int * int
   ```
2. Sum sequence of 3-tuples:

   ```
   > let sumRGBSeq seq = seq |> Seq.fold sumRGB (0,0,0);;

   val sumRGBSeq : seq:seq<int * int * int> -> int * int * int
   ```
3. Test the solution:

   ```
   > let source = [(123,143,136);(177,284,248);(143,182,252)];;

   val source : (int * int * int) list =
     [(123, 143, 136); (177, 284, 248); (143, 182, 252)]

   > sumRGBSeq source;;

   val it : int * int * int = (443, 609, 636)
   ```

**Update**

As @TomasPetricek pointer out, your current code does not calculate average, it calculates Sum of sequence of 3-tuples.

Comment: Using a separate `sumRGB` function has a certain beauty to it, because you can then quite nicely just write `seq |> Seq.fold sumRGBP (0,0,0)` :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's much nicer than with lambda! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This version doesn't include the average (as Tomas pointed out, builtin averages won't work for int), uses `List` instead of `Seq`, and it probably isn't as efficient, but it's a bit more succinct:

```
let (|||>) (a,b,c) fn  = (fn a, fn b, fn c)
let sumRGB rgb =  rgb |> List.unzip3 |||> List.sum
```